# Google Maps API - 'Method getUrl() is undefined'

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have no idea on what's happen about the error, please help me.

1. The method getUrl() is undefined for the type HttpRequest
2. The method createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer(){}) is undefined for the type HttpTransport
3. The constructor JsonHttpParser(JacksonFactory) is undefined

Am I missing any libraries?

thank you

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
public class GooglePlaces {

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

// Google API Key
private static final String API_KEY = "my-api-key";

// Google Places serach url's
private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

private double _latitude;
private double _longitude;
private double _radius;

/**
 * Searching places
 * @param latitude - latitude of place
 * @params longitude - longitude of place
 * @param radius - radius of searchable area
 * @param types - type of place to search
 * @return list of places
 * */
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
        throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;

    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 * Searching single place full details
 * @param refrence - reference id of place
 *                 - which you will get in search api request
 * */
public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

        PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

        return place;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}

/**
 * Creating http request Factory
 * */
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
        final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. It would be helpful if you could say more. As for your 3 errors, indeed those methods are not in the API.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old. But in case someone gets here with a similar problem, here is what worked for me.

It seems I had some conflicting dependencies:

```
//implementation("com.google.api.client:google-api-client-json:1.2.3-alpha")
//implementation("com.google.api.client:google-api-client-util:1.2.3-alpha")
implementation("com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.40.0")
implementation("com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.40.0")
```

When I removed the first two, it worked.

In my investigations, I saw that the jar file `google-http-client-1.40.0-sources.jar` had the missing method (on Intellij, I used the command "go to declaration or usage"), while in the `HttpTransport.class` file decompiled from `External Libraries` did not have it.